# Error adding RAD Studio project to Subversion

Tags: delphi, svn, visualsvn, rad-studio

I'm trying to add my Delphi project to Subversion repository, but have an error.

I have extracted all binaries of VisualSVN 1.14.2 to folder and specified it in IDE settings. Then I do right-click -> Add to Version Control, select "SubVersion", paste URL of repository, specify Import Comment and click "Import". After that I have the following error:
[image: Import error]
Can anyone explain what it means? I have created an empty repository on Subversion server and specified its URL while importing. How the path https://.../svn even related to it?

Comment: In short: the SVN functionality built into the IDE is crap. Better use an external tool like TortoiseSVN. There can also be found a TortoiseSVN plugin for Delphi.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)